# Big Query how to change mode of columns?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I have a Dataflow pipeline that fetches data from Pub/Sub and prepares them for insertion into Big Query and them writes them into the Database.

It works fine, it can generate the schema automatically and it is able to recognise what datatype to use and everything.

However the data we are using with it can vary vastly in format. Ex: we can get both A and B for a single column

```
A {"name":"John"}

B {"name":["Albert", "Einstein"]}
```

If the first message we get gets added, then adding the second one will not work.

If i do it the other way around it does however.

i always get the following error:

```
 

INFO:root:Error: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/project/projectname/jobs?uploadType=resumable: Provided Schema does not match Table project:test_dataset.test_table. Field cars has changed mode from NULLABLE to REPEATED with loading dataframe
ERROR:apache_beam.runners.direct.executor:Exception at bundle <apache_beam.runners.direct.bundle_factory._Bundle object at 0x7fcb9003f2c0>, due to an exception.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
........

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
   Provided Schema does not match Table project.test_table. Field cars has changed mode from NULLABLE to REPEATED

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 582, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "newmain.py", line 211, in process
    if load_job and load_job.errors:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'load_job' referenced before assignment
```

Below is the code

```py
class WriteDataframeToBQ(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self, bq_dataset, bq_table, project_id):
        self.bq_dataset = bq_dataset
        self.bq_table = bq_table
        self.project_id = project_id

    def start_bundle(self):
        self.client = bigquery.Client()

    def process(self, df):
        # table where we're going to store the data
        table_id = f"{self.bq_dataset}.{self.bq_table}"

        # function to help with the json -> bq schema transformations
        generator = SchemaGenerator(input_format='dict', quoted_values_are_strings=True, keep_nulls=True)

        # Get original schema to assist the deduce_schema function. If the table doesn't exist
        # proceed with empty original_schema_map
        try:
            table = self.client.get_table(table_id)
            original_schema = table.schema
            self.client.schema_to_json(original_schema, "original_schema.json")
            with open("original_schema.json") as f:
                original_schema = json.load(f)
                original_schema_map, original_schema_error_logs = generator.deduce_schema(input_data=original_schema)
        except Exception:
            logging.info(f"{table_id} table not exists. Proceed without getting schema")
            original_schema_map = {}

        # convert dataframe to dict
        json_text = df.to_dict('records')

        # generate the new schema, we need to write it to a file because schema_from_json only accepts json file as input
        schema_map, error_logs = generator.deduce_schema(input_data=json_text, schema_map=original_schema_map)
        schema = generator.flatten_schema(schema_map)

        schema_file_name = "schema_map.json"
        with open(schema_file_name, "w") as output_file:
            json.dump(schema, output_file)

        # convert the generated schema to a version that BQ understands
        bq_schema = self.client.schema_from_json(schema_file_name)

        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
            schema_update_options=[
                bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION,
                bigquery.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION
            ],
            write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            schema=bq_schema
        )
        job_config.schema = bq_schema

        try:
            load_job = self.client.load_table_from_json(
                json_text,
                table_id,
                job_config=job_config,
            )  # Make an API request.

            load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
            if load_job.errors:
                logging.info(f"error_result =  {load_job.error_result}")
                logging.info(f"errors =  {load_job.errors}")
            else:
                logging.info(f'Loaded {len(df)} rows.')

        except Exception as error:
            logging.info(f'Error: {error} with loading dataframe')

            if load_job and load_job.errors:
                logging.info(f"error_result =  {load_job.error_result}")
                logging.info(f"errors =  {load_job.errors}")


def run(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, save_main_session=True, streaming=True)
    options = pipeline_options.view_as(JobOptions)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read PubSub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=options.input_subscription)
            | "Write Raw Data to Big Query" >> beam.ParDo(WriteDataframeToBQ(project_id=options.project_id, bq_dataset=options.bigquery_dataset, bq_table=options.bigquery_table))
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run(sys.argv)
```

Is there a way to change the restrictions of the table to make this work?

Comment: You need to define manually the schema to prevent wrong message order and thus bad schema creation. Or create your table prior to run your dataflow.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the data we are getting can be anything really. The goal is to make it adapt to whatever comes. I dont know what may turn into repeatable and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery isn't a document database, but a columnar oriented database. In addition, you can't update the schema of existing columns (only add or remove them).

For your use case, and because you can't know/predict the most generic schema of each of your field, the safer is to store the raw JSON as a string, and then to use the [JSON functions of BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) to post process, in SQL, your data

Comment: Is it possible then to make every new column created by it repeated by default?

Comment: No, you need to set a schema for that.